# Trying to use iw_statistics structure but having trouble?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a kernel where I need to read certain statistics from `iw_statistics` structure, here's the code:

```
struct net_device *dev; 
struct iw_statistics *wi_stats;
wi_stats = dev->wireless_handlers->get_wireless_stats(dev);
```

the code compiles correctly, but when trying to run it, the module gets stuck connot get removed ... I'm using linux kernel 2.6.35 and my wireless device is up and running, so the structure HAS to have some values in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that dev is initialized first. To initialize dev, you can do something like the following:

```
static struct net_device* getdev()
{
   struct net_device *dev; 
#ifndef CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT
   return NULL;
#endif     
   dev = first_net_device(&init_net);
   while (dev) {  
         if (dev->wireless_handles != NULL)
                 break;
         dev=next_net_device(dev);
   } 
   return dev; // if not found dev is NULL;
} 

struct iw_statistics *wi_stats=NULL;
struct net_device *dev = getdev();
if (dev) 
    wi_stats = dev->wireless_handlers->get_wireless_stats(dev);
else 
    printk("error finding wireless device");
if (!wi_stats)
    return;  // error wi_stats not configured.
```

Answer (score 1):

@ajpyles's answer may not work though

Cuz checking the device's name doesn't mean that it's a wireless adopter that's why `wireless_handlers` can be `NULL` leading to a crash in your system or getting your module stuck in linux kernel

Comment: that's exactly what's going on... any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: I assumed that you already know the name of the wireless adapter.  Are you looking for a generic solution that will work with all wireless adapters?

Comment: net_device is defined here. Does your kernel have CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT set? http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3/include/linux/netdevice.h#L1135

Comment: @Someone Anyhow I updated my solution for a more generic solution (Wireless adapter name not needed.)

Comment: Looks like CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT is not set, what sets it and where? can I manually set it?

Comment: @Someone yeah you will need to recompile the kernel and set that option in your .config file. If this is NOT set, however, check your wifi driver code. Chances are you will need to use another method to grab these statistics. Because if the driver code does not support this option, then you won't be able to retrieve these statistics.